# How to animate a relayout of NSCollectionViewLayout on bounds change?

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewflowlayout, nscollectionviewlayout

I have a basic implementation of `NSCollectionViewLayout` very similar to `NSCollectionViewFlowLayout`:

It places item in a horizontal row. If there's not enough room, the next item is added to the next row and so on.

My question: how can I animate a layout change when an item moves from the first row into the second row?

Here's an example:

[image: Relayout]

Note how item #3 "jumps" from the first to the second row. I'd like to animate that change.

There are lots of methods to animate adding/removing items, but I was not able to figure out how to animate layout changes when no items change.

Answer (score 0):

The methods you're looking to override in your layout subclass are [prepare(forAnimatedBoundsChange:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionviewlayout/1533678-prepare) and [finalizeAnimatedBoundsChange()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionviewlayout/1533163-finalizeanimatedboundschange).

From the documentation:

> ```
> open func prepare(forAnimatedBoundsChange oldBounds: NSRect) // NSCollectionView calls this when its bounds have changed inside an animation block before displaying items in its new bounds
> ```
>
> Prepares the layout object for animated changes to the collection view’s bounds or for the insertion or deletion of items.

> ```
> open func finalizeAnimatedBoundsChange() // also called inside the animation block
> ```
>
> Cleans up after any animated changes to the collection view’s bounds or after the insertion or deletion of items.

Comment: Can you expand this answer with some sample code? These are the right hooks, but it's not clear what code should be placed in the methods. Thanks.